# Convert DeserializeObject<object> to entity object doesnt work

Tags: serialization, deserialization

I want to convert deserialized object to an entity object like this:

```
 item.Data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Object>(reader["Data"].ToString());
 User user = item.Data as User;
```

but in second line, user set to null because item.Data cant convert to user, although following line works:

```
item.Data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(reader["Data"].ToString());
```

why?

Note: User class is like this:

```
 [Serializable]
public class User
{

    private string fullName, userName;
    private Enumes.UserType userType;
    private Int64 userCode;
    private Int32 userID;
    private string userTypeDesc;
    private string lastLoginIP;
    private string lastLoginTime;
    private List<Enumes.UserRole> userRole;
    private List<UserAccessLevel> userAccessLevel;
    private string mobilePhone;
    private string codeMelli;
    private string bDate;        
    private Enumes.UserCurrentStatus currentStatus;
    private string currentIPAddress;
 ...}
```

UserAccessLevel is Serializable too.

Comment: Check  reader["Data"].ToString() in correct json string format.

Comment: The format is correct because it deserialize to 'user' correctly, but when I deserialize it to 'object' , the object cant convert to user entity.